# What is the best way to create a JSON or Object into another Object in Javascript?

Tags: json, ajax, object

I'm getting a result from a database using ajax, like the code below:

```
success: function (dados) {
            $.each(dados, function () {
                $.each(this, function (index, value) { ... });
            });
        }
```

The return I'm getting from the database supposed to be featured like this:

```
[{_id: "001",
name: "John",
age: 38},

{_id: "002",
name: "Marie",
age: 27}]
```

And I'd like to have an object like this:

```
Object[_id] = {name: ..., age: ...}
```

So, for each _id, I'd have a name and age to iterate and handle with Javascript.
How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce:

```
let formattedObj = dados.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item._id] = {
        name: item.name, 
        age: item.age
    }

    return obj;
}, {});
```